# StartActivityForResult Service

Tags: android, mobile, service, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I have this app that connects to any model of Bluetooth Thermal Printer and prints a file with data about a product for an invoice.

When the user clicks to register a request for a product that file is created and the app opens a screen with 2 buttons: pair and print. When pair is clicked, a new Activity with a list of devices is opened and the user chooses a printer, it returns to the main 2 buttons activity and the connection is established.

It works because all this process is part of the Activity itself, the Bluetooth connection for example.

But, as you can imagine, if I connect to the printer and open another Activity, that connection is lost. I cant close the activity because the connection is bonded to it.

I need the app to maintain that Bluetooth connection between Activities so i can set a connection in a printer settings screen and just print the file when the register is done.

So I tried to create a Service, I created a Java class and just copy/pasted all this code into it, however, the StartActivityForResult() and onActivityResult() doesn't work on it (I need it to pass the selected device to the connection).

I don't know what to do, please help, I need this whole connection to work on the background.

This it the two buttons screen code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements Runnable {

protected static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
private static final int REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE = 1;
private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 2;
Button mScan, mPrint;

Thread mBlutoothConnectThread;

BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
private UUID applicationUUID = UUID
        .fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
private ProgressDialog mBluetoothConnectProgressDialog;
private BluetoothSocket mBluetoothSocket;
BluetoothDevice mBluetoothDevice;

TextView stat;
int printstat;

LinearLayout layout;

/* Get time and date */
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a", Locale.US);
final String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    stat = findViewById(R.id.bpstatus);

    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);

    layout = findViewById(R.id.layout);

    mScan = findViewById(R.id.Scan);
    mScan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View mView) {

            if (mScan.getText().equals("Connect")) {
                mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
                if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Message1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                        Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(
                                BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                        startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent,
                                REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
                    } else {
                        ListPairedDevices();
                        Intent connectIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                                DeviceListActivity.class);
                        startActivityForResult(connectIntent,
                                REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE);

                    }
                }

            } else if (mScan.getText().equals("Disconnect")) {
                if (mBluetoothAdapter != null)
                    mBluetoothAdapter.disable();
                stat.setText("");
                stat.setText("Disconnected");
                stat.setTextColor(Color.rgb(199, 59, 59));
                mPrint.setEnabled(false);
                mScan.setEnabled(true);
                mScan.setText("Connect");
            }
        }
    });


    mPrint = findViewById(R.id.mPrint);
    mPrint.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View mView) {

            p1();

            /* 5000 ms (5 Seconds) */
            int TIME = 10000;

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    /* print second copy */
                    p2();

                    printstat = 1;
                }
            }, TIME);

        }
    });

}

public void p1() {

    Thread t = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                OutputStream os = mBluetoothSocket.getOutputStream();
                
                String header = "";
                String he = "";
                he = "      Test\n";

                os.write(he.getBytes());
                os.write(header.getBytes());

                // Setting height
                int gs = 29;
                os.write(intToByteArray(gs));
                int h = 150;
                os.write(intToByteArray(h));
                int n = 170;
                os.write(intToByteArray(n));

                // Setting Width
                int gs_width = 29;
                os.write(intToByteArray(gs_width));
                int w = 119;
                os.write(intToByteArray(w));
                int n_width = 2;
                os.write(intToByteArray(n_width));
                
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("PrintActivity", "Exe ", e);
            }
        }
    };
    t.start();
}

public void p2() {

    Thread tt = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                OutputStream os = mBluetoothSocket.getOutputStream();

                String header = "";
                String he = "";
                he = "      Test\n";

                os.write(he.getBytes());
                os.write(header.getBytes());

                // Setting height
                int gs = 29;
                os.write(intToByteArray(gs));
                int h = 150;
                os.write(intToByteArray(h));
                int n = 170;
                os.write(intToByteArray(n));

                // Setting Width
                int gs_width = 29;
                os.write(intToByteArray(gs_width));
                int w = 119;
                os.write(intToByteArray(w));
                int n_width = 2;
                os.write(intToByteArray(n_width));

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("PrintActivity", "Exe ", e);
            }
        }
    };
    tt.start();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    /* Terminate bluetooth connection and close all sockets opened */
    try {
        if (mBluetoothSocket != null)
            mBluetoothSocket.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Tag", "Exe ", e);
    }
}


public void onActivityResult(int mRequestCode, int mResultCode,
                             Intent mDataIntent) {
    super.onActivityResult(mRequestCode, mResultCode, mDataIntent);

    switch (mRequestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE:
            if (mResultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Bundle mExtra = mDataIntent.getExtras();
                String mDeviceAddress = mExtra.getString("DeviceAddress");
                Log.v(TAG, "Coming incoming address " + mDeviceAddress);
                mBluetoothDevice = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(mDeviceAddress);
                mBluetoothConnectProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this,
                        "Connecting...", mBluetoothDevice.getName() + " : "
                                + mBluetoothDevice.getAddress(), true, false);
                mBlutoothConnectThread = new Thread(this);
                mBlutoothConnectThread.start();
                // pairToDevice(mBluetoothDevice); This method is replaced by
                // progress dialog with thread
            }
            break;

        case REQUEST_ENABLE_BT:
            if (mResultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                ListPairedDevices();
                Intent connectIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        DeviceListActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(connectIntent, REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Not connected to any device", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            break;
    }
}

private void ListPairedDevices() {
    Set<BluetoothDevice> mPairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter
            .getBondedDevices();
    if (mPairedDevices.size() > 0) {
        for (BluetoothDevice mDevice : mPairedDevices) {
            Log.v(TAG, "PairedDevices: " + mDevice.getName() + "  "
                    + mDevice.getAddress());
        }
    }
}

public void run() {
    try {
        mBluetoothSocket = mBluetoothDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(applicationUUID);
        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        mBluetoothSocket.connect();
        mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
    } catch (IOException eConnectException) {
        Log.d(TAG, "CouldNotConnectToSocket", eConnectException);
        closeSocket(mBluetoothSocket);
        return;
    }
}

private void closeSocket(BluetoothSocket nOpenSocket) {
    try {
        nOpenSocket.close();
        Log.d(TAG, "SocketClosed");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Log.d(TAG, "CouldNotCloseSocket");
    }
}


@SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        mBluetoothConnectProgressDialog.dismiss();

        stat.setText("");
        stat.setText("Connected");
        stat.setTextColor(Color.rgb(97, 170, 74));
        mPrint.setEnabled(true);
        mScan.setText("Disconnect");
    }
};

public static byte intToByteArray(int value) {
    byte[] b = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(value).array();

    for (int k = 0; k < b.length; k++) {
        System.out.println("Selva  [" + k + "] = " + "0x"
                + UnicodeFormatter.byteToHex(b[k]));
    }

    return b[3];
}

public void iThread(View view) {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity2.class));
}
```

}

This is the DeviceList class code:

```
public class DeviceListActivity extends Activity {
protected static final String TAG = "DeviceListActivity";
private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
private ArrayAdapter<String> mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle mSavedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(mSavedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_device_list);

    setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);
    mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.device_name);

    ListView mPairedListView = findViewById(R.id.paired_devices);
    mPairedListView.setAdapter(mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter);
    mPairedListView.setOnItemClickListener(mDeviceClickListener);

    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    Set<BluetoothDevice> mPairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

    if (mPairedDevices.size() > 0) {
        /* List of all paired devices */
        findViewById(R.id.title_paired_devices).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        for (BluetoothDevice mDevice : mPairedDevices) {
            mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter.add(mDevice.getName() + "\n" + mDevice.getAddress());
        }
    } else {
        /* No paired device */
        String mNoDevices = "None Paired";
        mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter.add(mNoDevices);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    /* Terminate bluetooth connection and close all sockets opened */
    if (mBluetoothAdapter != null) {
        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
    }
}

private OnItemClickListener mDeviceClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> mAdapterView, View mView, int mPosition, long mLong) {

        try {
            /* Attempt to connect to bluetooth device */
            mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
            String mDeviceInfo = ((TextView) mView).getText().toString();
            String mDeviceAddress = mDeviceInfo.substring(mDeviceInfo.length() - 17);
            Log.v(TAG, "Device_Address " + mDeviceAddress);

            Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
            mBundle.putString("DeviceAddress", mDeviceAddress);
            Intent mBackIntent = new Intent();
            mBackIntent.putExtras(mBundle);
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, mBackIntent);
            finish();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Error: " + ex);
        }
    }
};
```

}

Please help

Comment: "it returns to the main 2 buttons activity and the connection is established" -- do that last bit ("the connection is established") in your service. Keep the rest, involving the activities and UI, in your activity.

Comment: Can you show me a code example? I dont know exacly what to write...

Comment: I got most of this code downloaded from the web so I dont know exacly what the connection is and how to make it. Can you please show me an example of a service that connects to the bluetooth printer?